# What happened to Scrad?

Tags: character, men-in-black-2

In *Men in Black II*, Johnny Knoxville's character Scrad, the two-headed alien henchman for Seelena leads a bunch of aline thugs to Jeebs' basement where Agent K has just been deneuralized.

In the ensuing fight he disappears, never to be seen again in the film which is strange considering he played a significant role in the story.

What happened? Victim of the cutting room?

Comment: Simply no answer. Only speculations are possible.

Answer (score 1):

It could be so that because Charlie felt sick they quit working for Serleena or uncut scene Kay killed them. [(meninblack.wikia.com)](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Scrad)

Another explanation can be-

> The worms tell J that some guy with 2 heads kidnapped Laura, so
>   obviously it was Johnny Knoxville's character. He probably waited for
>   further orders from Serleena after completing this task, but they
>   never came.[(source)](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film2453/questions)